# eband_local_planner configuration

Tags: ros, navigation, eband-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello !

I try to use the elastic band planner in order to do navigation for an omni-directional robot.
My question is: How to configure the *eband_local_planner* for omni-directional or holonomic navigation ?

I don't find any specific parameter for this planner on the following website: http://wiki.ros.org/eband_local_planner 
I tried to use *base_local_planner* parameters but using *EBandPlannerROS* instead of *TrajectoryPlannerROS* but it doesn't works (nothing changes).
If this planner is configurable, how to do this ?

If anyone can help me (or just giving me the list of parameters for the eband_local_planner), I will be grateful,
lfr

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236164/eband_local_planner-configuration/) by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-06-09**:
Please open a github issue about the lack of documentation.

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-10**:
It's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, we can find most of the parameters here: [eband_trajectory_controller.cpp - "initialize" function](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/eband_local_planner/html/eband__trajectory__controller_8cpp_source.html)
Moreover the documentation for the eband_local_planner parameters on the ROS website is under construction.

Thanks to all,
lfr

---

Originally posted by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) with karma: 201 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure if the eband_local_planner has a setting to select between holonomic, and non-holonomic robots. To me, it seems like it is currently configured to work with both.

As for finding the parameters, you can look through the initialize section of the planner to see what parameters are available: [Line 84 in eband_local_planner.cpp](https://github.com/utexas-bwi/eband_local_planner/blob/master/src/eband_local_planner.cpp#L84)

Unfortunately, I no longer have my `.yaml` file from when I experimented with this planner to share with you, but you should be able to put it together from here following the format of other parameter files.

---

Originally posted by [Steven_Daniluk](https://answers.ros.org/users/25049/steven_daniluk/) with karma: 606 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lfr](https://answers.ros.org/users/26831/lfr/) on 2016-06-08**:
Thank you for your answer. I use a youbot base in simulation but the eband_local_planner provides just non-holonomic movements. I found that there are too few parameters specified in the cpp file and none for setting the type of movement.
Thank you again for answering me.